# Webpage to not delete form data after refresh

Tags: javascript, html, forms, page-refresh, onsubmit

I have a form on a website that requires two text inputs and two radio inputs *(one radio input currently not working because I can't figure out how to get them both to print instead of one overwriting the other)*. Upon hitting submit, the information posts underneath the form. I am trying to make it so that when the page is refreshed, the previously entered information will not disappear. Is there a simple way to achieve this?

I have heard about setting return onsubmit=false but have had no success so far.

```html
<!--COMMENTING FORM-->
                <div>
                   <div id="getdata">
                   <form id="form1"  onsubmit="return confirmdata(false)">

                        <!--Input (text) asking for input of name-->
                      <p><b>Name:</b><br><input type="text" name="nameValue" value="" id="nameValue"></p>

                      <!--Input (radio) asking for type of output: 
                      <p><b>Type of Event:</b></p>
                        <input type="radio" name="eventType" value="Food"> Food</br>
                        <input type="radio" name="eventType" value="Study"> Study</br>
                        <input type="radio" name="eventType" value="Event"> Event</br>
                        <input type="radio" name="eventType" value="Danger"> Danger</br>

                        TO DO FIX LATER -->

                      <!--Input (radio) asking for location: -->
                      <br>
                      <p><b>Location:</b></p>
                        <input type="radio" name="locationType" value="Library West"> Library West</br>
                        <input type="radio" name="locationType" value="Smathers Library"> Smathers Library</br>
                        <input type="radio" name="locationType" value="Marston Library"> Marston Library</br>
                        <input type="radio" name="locationType" value="Turlington Plaza"> Turlington Plaza</br>

                      <!--Input (text) asking for input of description-->
                      <br>
                      <p><b>Description:</b><br><input type="text" style="width:200px; height:50px;" name="desValue" value="" id="desValue"></p>

                        <!--submit button-->
                        <p><input type="submit" name="myButton" value="Submit!">
                        <input type="reset" value="Reset Form"></p>
                   </form>

                   </div>  

                   <div id="confirm">
                   </div>

                </div>
                </body>
                <!--COMMENTING FORM END-->

                <!-- COMMENTING FORM SCRIPT -->  
                <script type="text/javascript">
                var txt1 = document.getElementById('nameValue');
                var types = document.getElementsByName('eventType');
                var types = document.getElementsByName('locationType');
                var txt2 = document.getElementById('desValue');

                document.getElementById("form1").addEventListener("submit", confirmdata);

                function confirmdata(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var nameValue = txt1.value;
                    var selected = 'none';
                    var desValue = txt2.value;

                    for (var i = 0; i < types.length; i++) {
                        if (types[i].checked === true) {
                            selected = types[i].value;
                        }
                    }
                        if (selected !== 'none' && nameValue !== '') {
                            //document.getElementById("confirm").innerHTML += '<p><b>Name:</b> ' + nameValue + '</p>';
                            //document.getElementById("confirm").innerHTML += '<p><b>Event Type:</b> ' + selected + '</p>';
                            //document.getElementById("confirm").innerHTML += '<p><b>Additional Details: </b>' + desValue + '</p>';
                            document.getElementById("confirm").innerHTML += '<p> User <b>' + nameValue + '</b> has an event located at <b>' + selected + '</b>. <br><b> Additional details: </b>' + desValue + '</p>';
                            document.getElementById("confirm").innerHTML += '<p><b>--------------------</b> ' + '</p>';
                        } else {
                            alert('Invalid input');
                        }
                        return false;
                }
                </script>
                <!-- COMMENTING FORM SCRIPT END --> 

             
            
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

either store the information on local storage or intercept the onsubmit event (edit: as a result, form submission triggers js function, but not page reload).

```
<form onsubmit="return myFunction()">
  <!-- put form elements here -->
</form>

<script>
function myFunction(){
  //do stuff here
  return false
}
</script>
```

You could always use ajax for form submission without reloading.

Answer (score 0):

you can store the data in browser local storage and on page load take the data from local storage and place in required fields. Always clear the locally stored data once form submitted successfully. Be sure not to store personal data there are high chances of data leak if it is a shared PC.